# Avoiding overflow in integer multiplication followed by division

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, numbers

I have two integral variables `a` and `b` and a constant `s` resp. `d`. I need to calculate the value of `(a*b)>>s` resp. `a*b/d`. The problem is that the multiplication may overflow and the final result will not be correct even though `a*b/d` could fit in the given integral type.

How could that be solved efficiently? The straightforward solution is to expand the variable `a` or `b` to a larger integral type, but there may not be a larger integral type. Is there any better way to solve the problem?

Comment: I infer that `d` is always `1<<s`. Is that true?

Comment: Your best bet is to expand into a larger integral type.

Comment: There's always a larger integral type: `struct uint_twice_max { uintmax_t upper, lower; };`. I'll leave defining the operations to you :p

Comment: Wild guess here, but if you know for sure the final result will be small enough, why not divide before multiplying (if at all possible in your context)?  a/d*b == a*b/d.

Comment: @pwny: That may result in reduced accuracy, particularly if `d` and `b` are large.

Comment: Do you want a rounded integral or a floating point as an answer?

Comment: The only way you will be able to avoid multiplication overflow in all regards is to use some form of a larger integral type, or covert to floating point. Take the case where s=0 and a*b results in overflow. There is no way to handle this case and remain in the same integral type you started with. Oli's example below is a way to wedge your integral type into multiple integrals if no larger integral is available. Bignum libraries will also help you.

Comment: @Swiss: I don't need to handle the overflow when the numerical (mathematical) result is not representable. I only want it to give correct result if it may be represented by the given integral type.

Comment: Are you implementing fixed point numbers?

Comment: How about doing a*(b/d)? Depending on your problem (floating point vs. integral type, required accuracy), it might just solve it :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If there isn't a larger type, you will either need to find a big-int style library, or deal with it manually, using long multiplication.

For instance, assume `a` and `b` are 16-bit.  Then you can rewrite them as `a = (1<<8)*aH + aL`, and `b = (1<<8)*bH + bL` (where all the individual components are 8-bit numbers).  Then you know that the overall result will be:

```
(a*b) = (1<<16)*aH*bH
      + (1<<8)*aH*bL
      + (1<<8)*aL*bH
      + aL*bL
```

Each of these 4 components will fit a 16-bit register.  You can now perform e.g. right-shifts on each of the individual components, being careful to deal with carries appropriately.

Comment: I think the problem as stated is that a*b might not fit into 16 bits, although a*b/d is guaranteed to fit. Thus your solution doesn't help.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: It does.  With my method, you need no 32-bit values.

Comment: Yes, this would work, but there seems to be some wasted calculations in this solution. I wonder if it could not be somehow merged with the division (right shift) to get a more efficient code.

Comment: @Juraj: If `s` is larger than 8 or 16, then yes, you can eliminate some of the less-significant calculations.  But in the general case, it's probably quicker to calculate all of them, rather than doing conditional operations.

Comment: If `s` is a compile-time constant and you use templates (C++), the compiler will do all the necessary optimizations.

Comment: Good answer. We can add overflow checks aH*bH > d and M > 255*d where M = aH*bL + aL*bH.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't exhaustively tested this, but could you do the division first, then account for the remainder, at the expense of extra operations? Since `d` is a power of two, all the divisions can be reduced to bitwise operations.

For example, always assume `a > b` (you want to divide the larger number first). Then `a * b / d` = `((a / d) * b) + (((a % d) * b) / d)`

Comment: I think `(a % d) * b` could still overflow (the largest possible value is `(d-1)*b`).

Comment: you can use the same technique as Mark B explained for the ((a%d)*b)/d part, seeing a%d as b and b as a.

Comment: @steabart: Yes, that's true.  You need to recurse as many times as it takes to be safe.

Comment: divisions are expensive. So expensive that the VC++ compiler replaces a division(with constant denominator) by an overflowing multiplication combined with some bit fiddling.

Comment: If `d > a` then the recursive step is the original problem, and this doesn't help

Answer (score 4):

If the larger type is just 64 bits then the straight forward solution will most likely result in efficient code. On x86 CPUs any multiplication of two 32 bit numbers will give the overflow in another register. So if your compiler understands that, it can generate efficient code for `Int64 result=(Int64)a*(Int64)b`.

I had the same problem in C#, and the compiler generated pretty good code. And C++ compilers typically create better code than the .net JIT.

I recommend writing the code with the casts to the larger types and then inspect the generated assembly code to check if it's good.

Comment: I have looked at disassembly and `int32_t result = (int64_t(a)*int64_t(b))>>2` generates nice code (just `imul` for multiplication). But when the b is constant, compiler generates `call _allmul`. That seems a little strange. I will have to look deeper into it.

Answer (score 0):

In certain cases (historically LCG random number generators with selected constants), it is possible to do what you want, for some values of a and d.

This is called Schrage's method, see eg. [there](http://beam.acclab.helsinki.fi/~djurabek/mc/Schrage_proof.pdf).