# Optimal way to do unsigned integer multiplication (with overflow) followed by division by the maximum value

Tags: c++, int, integer-overflow, integer-division

I have the following problem - I have 3 unsigned integers: a,b,c. c is the maximum value that the unsigned integer type I am using can take(so a<=c && b<=c). I know that a*b may overflow, and I know that the number (a * b / c) does not overflow (basically I need the number that one would get if he casts a,b,c to an unsigned integer type with enough bits and performs the multiplication and division). What is **the fastest** way to find the number (a * b / c) without having to cast to an unsigned integer type with more bits (preferably with the lowest error possible)?

I am currently using float casting, and I was wondering whether there was a method that produces results that are better and faster. I know that a*b/c can be expressed as either a/(c/b) or b/(c/a), with the option of expanding the remainder too, but depending on how many times I expand it, the error can be big, and I am not exactly sure how that compares in terms of speed to float casting and performing the division in float.  I have looked at: [Avoiding overflow in integer multiplication followed by division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542037/avoiding-overflow-in-integer-multiplication-followed-by-division) though I was hoping that with the given additional information about a,b,c a better/faster method may be used. The post I linked also doesn't mention anything about speed.

Edit: It's also preferable for the method to work fast on the GPU too, but not necessary.
Edit2: If anybody's wondering why I would need this - I am using uint to represent numbers in [0,1], since I need arithmetic operations to not accumulate error.

Comment: Think of the unsigned integer type I am talking about as uint32, so yes I do have the option of using uint64, but I want a solution without having to cast to uint64.

Comment: That's interesting. Sorry being not constructive, but what are these reasons?

Comment: Mainly speed, cache(think of an array of elements) and possibly the code going on the GPU.  I am not sure if what I am asking is even feasible, I was just hoping that somebody may know of something, I hoped the constraints on the problem would help.

Comment: Speed? I think that would be the fastest way to do this. Cache? What is cache has to do with this problem? GPU reason might be acceptable...

Comment: Wide integer would be used just as a temporary, there is no cache involved here

Comment: By cache I meant that I would change my whole array to uint64, if I wanted to just do all my operations effectively(without casting etc), which would result in cache misses with the arrays I am working with. I am aware that I can just cast it for the operations, but it's preferable that things stay in uint32. Intrinsics are fine I guess, if they perform as fast or faster than float casting(I cast to float since it's 32 bits also).

Comment: Casting from uint32 to uint64 is basically free, so you should keep storing your numbers in uint32

Comment: I guess you're right, that still leaves me with the gpu and the speed problem though. I think the problem may be formulated in another way, since I am dividing by the biggest number, which in this case is 2^32 - 1, I guess getting the hi 32 bits is a good solution, many thanks to harold for that solution.

Comment: Ah. I'm sure that there is a formula for that, if `c` is a constant 2^32-1

Comment: There's a library for this: http://libdivide.com/. But it is possibile, that for 2^32-1, there is a simpler method. Something like `>>32`, and then a fixup needed in certain cases

Comment: The other problem is I need to do the same for uint64, so I don't really have the option of casting to a bigger uint). I guess some decomposition in hi and low parts, could do the trick, but I am not sure how fast that is (is it worth it using it over float).

Comment: Actually, if you are on 64-bit, then there is the option. There is a 128-bit type in GCC (and maybe on other compilers as well).

Comment: CUDA has the corresponding __umul64hi, MSVC has __umulh and GCC has a 128b type

Comment: Here's a formula I've found for dividing by 2^32-1: `(x+(x>>32)+1)>>32`. It is precise for all values of `x`, except 2^64-1.

Comment: I think you cannot get 2^64-1 anyways if your numbers are <=2^32-1. I'll just stick with x>>32, even though (2^32-1)>>32 == 0, but at least it's fast(and an error of 1 is fine for my purpose). But I guess that solution is good, if no error is permitted.

Comment: For preciseness, I meant that it gives the same result as division (even when there's overflow, it happens sooner than 2^64-1). If there's no overflow, then this formula is correct for every `x`.